# React-Native fetch() Network Request Failed on Android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, fetch, react-native

Background:
I'm using react-native and rails and developing on a Kindle Fire HD tablet.
When I use fetch to try to connect to the rails server running locally on my macbook, I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (index.android.bundle:12432)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (index.android.bundle:15169)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (index.android.bundle:14953)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (index.android.bundle:14809)
    at index.android.bundle:14904
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (index.android.bundle:5866)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (index.android.bundle:4838)
    at index.android.bundle:4654
    at MessageQueue.__guard (index.android.bundle:4809)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (index.android.bundle:4653)
```

Here is the fetch request.

```
fetch('https://192.168.X.X:8080/api/collections', {
    method: 'GET',
    body: null,
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson)
    return success(responseJson);
})
.catch((err) => {
    errors(err);
});
```

Searching around, most of the suggestions say to replace the localhost/127.0.0.1 to the ip of the server. But that seems to not have helped.

Comment: Can you access the api endpoint from your tablet using a browser (i.e. Chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Mac port is open, it isn’t by default.  Also make sure the firewall s either off or allowing the connections through.

Comment: Yup, the firewall is off.

Comment: Not sure on fire tablet I would try using axios or something I've had odd issues in the past with built in fetch myself so I quit using it for now.

Comment: Just tried using axios for the same get request and am still getting a network error. If I run send a request via the console on my macbook everything works fine, but sending it through my tablet seems to be giving me the network error.